# ros distro "N" version not released?

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it says here

http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions

Every May it is expected to be published a ros version.

I know that we have ros2 Dashing Diademata, but if I am not wrong they are independent releases (at least it has a specific distro page (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/) .

I just use LTS versions of ros but, I am quite curious.

Does anybody know something? Maybe they are deciding to remove the non LTS version to focus more in ros2 ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324973/ros-distro-%22n%22-version-not-released?/) by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2019-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://discourse.ros.org/t/planning-future-ros-1-distribution-s/6538 for the plan for Noetic which is targeted for May 2020.

Since non-LTS releases have never been used much there is no ROS 1 release in 2019.

---

Edit: the [Distributions/ReleasePolicy](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions/ReleasePolicy) page has been updated ([diff](http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/Distributions/ReleasePolicy?action=diff)).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-07**:
Should the Distributions page not be updated to reflect this?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-06-07**:
Yes, that would be good.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-07**:
Your answer implies you / OR are not going to do that. Is that correct?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-06-07**:
I will delegate it to the ROS boss of Noetic. So it will get updated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-07**:\

> ROS boss

nice one.

> So it will get updated.

Ok, great. It's not that 'others' don't know how to edit a wiki page, but it'd be good to have an authoritative source do that. Just so we don't communicate more incorrect information.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-06-07**:\

> ROS boss

That is more of an internal name than an official title though ;-)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-07**:
Hm. So no business cards then ? ;)

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2019-06-14**:
Thanks! :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-14**:
Could you click the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as answered?